# Windows 10 - Environment Variables doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, php, environment-variables

I'm installing php, so I added C:\PHP7 to my env variable %path%. I run the cmd with administrator access, and when

```
echo %path%
```

The result is:

```
C:\PHP7\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\hendr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

Here is screenshot from cmd:

[image]

But I still can't execute php.exe (which is located in C:\PHP7) in any folder. What' I've missed here ?

Comment: Can you execute PHP in any folder by writing C:\PHP7\php.exe ?

Comment: @duDE Yes I can.

Comment: Please [edit] and include the full output from running the `PATH` command in a `cmd` shell.

Comment: @DavidPostill Done. Please check.

Comment: @HendryH., we are always glad to help but rather than replying with a different account than the one that authored the question, please ask the moderators to have your two accounts merged.

Comment: @Run5k Sorry, you mean two accounts as 1 in stack overflow and 1 in superuser ? Who should I contact to merge my accounts ? Need guidance here. super new

Comment: No problem, it can be a bit confusing.  I actually mean that you have two Super User accounts:  [this one](http://superuser.com/users/698269/hendry-h) and [this one](http://superuser.com/users/698270/hendry-h).  You can ask the staff for help at the following page:  [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @Run5k Yes I just realized that... Already having a chat with moderator. Thank you. :)

Comment: You're welcome... I know that the mods will take good care of you.

Comment: @Run5k Done, no more confusion. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try with php.exe in bin folder. Add bin folder to PATH env. variable.

Comment: My folder installation doesn't have bin folder. And yes I tried to create bin folder myself, and copy php.exe to bin folder, add bin folder to env. And still I can't just type php.exe directly.

Comment: Speculative suggestions are better as a comment. [from review](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/626350).